# Wordpress blog posts have no <a href="url_to_blogpost">

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have encountered a very weird issue after the last update to WP 4.4.1 and it's that the **href attribute** on all blog posts in the website.com/blog section are missing, so the link looks like this:

```
<a href="" title="Most read articles in the previous year">Most read articles in the previous year</a>
```

The articles are normally accessible and have the **href** **attribute** from the front page of the blog, where they point to: website.com/texts/name_of_the_blogpost just not from website.com/blog

Did anyone else ever experience such an issue, and could the update of WP be the reason for it? Everything worked normally until the update.

Comment: Isn't the wordpress website a better place to ask these questions? 
https://wordpress.org

Comment: Or use special stack exchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your theme may use a now deprecated (under 4.4.1) WordPress function. Switch to the default WordPress twentyfifteen or twentysixteen theme for a minute and see if the php function correctly outputs the URLs of the blog posts. If so, it's your theme. Talk to the theme developer or take a look at the functions in theme files, the query loop, etc. No one can help more until you post some code.

Comment: Thanks @markratledge this really helps! It might be the theme itself, and I will check what's going on in the functions, the theme is a bit older so this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorted it out, seems like in the content.php file there was a permalink function in the a href which was not written correctly at all: <?php the_permalink(' ') ?> - don't know what might have caused it, but it is corrected now :)